# My custom JavaScript within my Blazor application is loading but not "working", functions are not callable

Tags: javascript, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop

In my Bootstrap project I use several JavaScript files. I load these files like so:

**App.razor**

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/popper/popper.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/JavaScript.js"); // This is my custom JavaScript
    }
}
```

However, when I try to use **any** of my custom JavaScript (JavaScript.js), it doesn't work.

When I try calling it "directly" like so:

```
<span onclick="myJSFunction();"> click me </span>
```

The browser gives me the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myJSFunction is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick ((index):1)
```

When I try to call it through Blazor like so:

```
<span @onclick="myFunction"> click me </span>
@code {
    [Inject]
    IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    private async Task myFunction()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("myJSFunction", "some text");
    }
}
```

Blazor gives me this error:

```
Error: Could not find 'myJSFunction' ('myJSFunction' was undefined).
```

I know my JavaScript.js is loading because I put this at the end of the file:

```
alert("I'm Loaded");
```

And the alert box always pops up.

The frustrating thing is that all the other `.JS` files I load are working properly.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you post what the function `myJSFunction` inside of `JavaScript.js` looks like?

Comment: @BenSampica It can be any function. Even something as simple as `function myAlert(){ alert("Hello, world!");}`. I even tried `export function myAlert(){ alert("Hello, world!");}`

Comment: Can you access myJSFunction in the browser console?

Comment: Usually, the inaccessibility of the function indicates some of syntax errors, which can be easily checked by loading the js code in the console.

Comment: @user1787509 I get no errors in the browser console unless I try to call it "directly" like so: `<span onclick="myJSFunction();"> click me </span>`.